# Why does splitting single pdf into multiple pdf files lead to an increasing memory size?

Tags: pdf, ms-word

Why does splitting single pdf into multiple pdf files lead to an increasing memory size?

[image]

In addition, is there any way to insert a multi-page pdf into a word file without increasing too much memory size? It seems that the word application can only show the first page of a multi-page pdf when inserting it as an attachment.

Comment: Hi, K J, thanks for your prompt answer. Yes, the increased memory should be caused by the duplicated embedded fonts. As a solution to view all pages in word, I split a multi-page pdf into single ones and inserted them into word. It works. Nevertheless, It seems unavoidable to view all pages without increased memory size at this moment. Many thanks : )

Comment: While it's likely that it's due to embedded fonts here, other resources can also be shared in a PDF, e.g. logo images for page headers, watermarks,... Thus, even in PDFs without text splitting can increase the size.

Comment: Hi, mkl, thanks for your answer. Yes, there should be some shared memory in a single file : )